# Menu-like UI with Checkbox and Popup

Tags: wpf, binding

I made a menu-like UI with Checkbox and Popup.

```
<CheckBox Name="Menu" />
<Popup Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Menu}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=IsChecked}" AllowsTransparency="True"  PopupAnimation="Slide" >
...
</Popup>
```

When a user clicks "Menu" button, the popup shows above the button. And click again, it hides.

I make a STYLE of this popup, following;

```
<Style x:Key="MenuPopup" TargetType="Popup">
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="IsOpen">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="IsChecked" Source="PlacementTarget"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Slide" />
</Style>
```

Using this style, code is very simple;

```
<CheckBox Name="Menu" />
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Menu}" Style="{StaticResource MenuPopup} >
...
</Popup>
```

But when a user clicks "Menu" button, nothing happen.

The 'Source' property of Binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for your binding should not be the `PlacementTarget`, but the `Popup` itself. Change

```
<Binding Path="IsChecked" Source="PlacementTarget"/>
```

to

```
<Binding Path="PlacementTarget.IsChecked" RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}"/>
```

And it will work.